# Learning Rails, workshop, course, resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Trying to learn rails, but the beast is quite complex for a beginner :)
Anybody knows of courses, workshops, mentoring etc  In London Uk.

I don't have a programming background, bu i'm a web designer/developper.

Cheers

Comment: Its not right place of such question .

Answer (score 1):

I know this doesn't directly answer you current question but I found that the Ruby On Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl really helped me.

Here is a link: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book?version=3.2

Comment: Yop i've got that :). Guess i'm looking for local support, minds i could scratch as it becomes pretty hairy when ones try to roll it's own thing. But Been told off it's not the right place to ask this question. so i shut up now :)